# Как преобразовать строку json в ассоциативный массив Java

Tags: java, json

Как преобразовать строку json в ассоциативный массив Java

`{"ts":"413","updates":[{"type":"message_new","object":{"message":{"date":1646661872,"from_id":100001,"id":0,"out":0,"attachments":[],"conversation_message_id":259,"fwd_messages":[],"important":false,"is_hidden":false,"peer_id":2000000001,"random_id":0,"text":"1"},"client_info":{"button_actions":["text","vkpay","open_app","location","open_link","callback","intent_subscribe","intent_unsubscribe"],"keyboard":true,"inline_keyboard":true,"carousel":true,"lang_id":0}},"group_id":100001,"event_id":"37cdcb763885ce3f8d96c17eccb7ebc0dc00"}]`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование строки json в HashMap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388190/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-json-%d0%b2-hashmap)

Comment: Какой именно ассоциативный массив/хэш-таблицу и почему вы ожидаете получить в результате?  Также не следует копировать однотипные вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть библеотека Jackson .
Jackson — Java библиoтeka для paбoты c дaнныmи в фopmaтe JSON.
Вам нужно только погуглить , при чем это очень легко делается, вы пока создавали этот вопрос , уже давно бы нашли ответ в гугле имхо

Вот к примеру преобразовать в Map

```
JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
Map<String, String> map = jsonMapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Проблема лишь в том, что в данном случае не получается мапа со строковыми ключами и главное значениями.